# Mapstruct - ignore a particular field in nested classes

Tags: java, mapstruct

I needed some help with mapping a nested POJO using MapStruct. I need skip/igonre a particular field from all the subclasses in my target class.

For e.g., following is my target POJO

```
class FullCustomerInfo {

    UnitIdInfo unitIdInfo;
    CustomerIdInfo customerIdInfo;
    NameInfo nameInfo;
    CustomerTypeInfo customerTypeInfo;
    AddressInfo addressInfo;

}
```

All of these subclasses - `UnitIdInfo`, `CustomerIdInfo`, `NameInfo` ... contain a field "`fieldToIgnore`" which I want to ignore while mapping. The structure is such that these classes donot share a common base class which contains this field - "`fieldToIgnore`".

The mapper I created looks like this:

```
@Mapper
public interface MapFullCustomer {

    @Mappings({
            @Mapping(target = "unitIdInfo.fieldToIgnore", ignore = true),
            @Mapping(target = "customerIdInfo.fieldToIgnore", ignore = true),
            @Mapping(target = "nameInfo.fieldToIgnore", ignore = true),
            @Mapping(target = "customerTypeInfo.fieldToIgnore", ignore = true),
            @Mapping(target = "addressInfo.fieldToIgnore", ignore = true)
    })
    public FullCustomerInfo map(SourceCustomerInfo sourceCustomerInfo);

}
```

This works.

However, it becomes tedious when the number of sub-classes in the `FullCustomerInfo` is large. I need to explicitly specify each and every class.

Can someone please advise me if this can be done in a more generic way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The easy way is to have all the classes to extend a base class containing the `fieldToIgnore` common field.

If that not suits you could try implmenting a customr that set all the fields to null with the help of java reflection api: https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#adding-custom-methods

I don't think it is worth the effort.